# Titanium: how to schedule events at specific date time

Tags: events, calendar, titanium, appcelerator, schedule

I need to schedule events at specific date time (for example an alert at birtdate) just like a calendar, eventually also with recurrence. I need to do this in [Appcelerator Titanium](http://www.appcelerator.com/mobile-app-development-products/). I've tried this [module](https://github.com/benbahrenburg/benCoding.AlarmManager) but no notifications are displayed at trigger time. Any idea how to accomplish this in Titanium?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you store your alerts on the server, and send the app a push notification whenever an event occurs? There are plenty of .(server-side) frameworks available to help you achieve this logic

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but actually i can't use push notifications. The schedule logic must work in locale, without connection

Comment: Adding it to the OS calendar isn't an option, I guess? (eg. http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Calendar see topic 'Create a Recurring Event with Alerts on iOS'

Comment: The problem with Calendar is that you can't edit or set recurring events in android. From what i have found the only option for me is to use the AlarmManager, is that right?